# Wireless LAN connection doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.10, how to fix it?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Dell studio 1537. All was fine until after a short time the WLAN connection stopped working and I was disconnected. The same thing happened when I re-installed Ubuntu. The network has stopped working and disappears from "network connections"

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first turn your router off and on again. If that doesn't help press Ctrl-Alt-t. A terminal will pop up, run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You'll be prompted for your password, as you type it in there's no feedback; that's normal. Press enter.

If that doesn't solve the issue, edit your question and post the output of the following terminal commands:

```
lspci -v | grep -iA 10 'network'

lsmod

rfkill list all

sudo lshw -c network

iwconfig
```

---

min info for now:

`lspci - v | grep -iA 10 'network'`: Device name after "Network controller:", "Kernel driver in use:", "Kernel Modules"

`lsmod`: check if the Kernel driver from lspci appears in the output

`rfkill list all`: For Wireless LAN does it say `Soft blocked: yes` or `Hard blocked: yes`, anywhere?

don't post that info in the comments below, but edit your question and post it there.

---

try this in the terminal:

```
sudo rmmod -f dell-laptop
```

then

```
sudo rfkill unblock all

rfkill list all
```

does it say "blabla blocked: yes" anywhere

check wifi connection again.

Report back

Comment: Router off/on is not working, next step too.

Comment: And the Output for the other commands is "no such file or directory" on every line.

Comment: I think I got the right Output, but can't post it with my phone..

Comment: those are 5 separate commands. Run them individually one after the other and make sure the spelling is right. The commands are case-sensitive so: `grep -iA 'network'` is different than `grep -ia 'network'`

Comment: Ok what informations are important? Can't write all with my mobile phone

Comment: connect to your router through an ethernet cable. You should at least have an ethernet connection.

Comment: Ethernet don't work too..